# TarFile.extractall() processes fine but doesn't create any new files or directories

Tags: python, python-2.7, compression, tar, stringio

Version: Python 2.7 
OS: MacOS Mojave 
IDE: Pycharm Community 2019.2

I'm having trouble downloading tar.gz files from `pypi.org/project` and unzipping them. The use case for this is that we can't use any actual package management, so we have to manually put packages where we need them in the local folders. My solution to this is to read a requirements file and pull the tar.gz and .zip files for the given versions and then write to local files.

I've got it working for zip files, and it works exactly how I want it to. Zip files are handled by the 'elif' statement, tar files are handled by the 'if' statement. For some reason, for the tar file links I pass in, no directories are created, no files are extracted.

I did a test by putting the path to my local copy of a tar file directly in this line `tarData = tarfile.open(fileobj=zipData, mode='r:*')` instead of `zipData` and it worked, so I think it has something to do with the format the file is being either downloaded in or handled in StringIO, but I'm not getting any exceptions so I have no way to narrow down what the issue could be.

The below is the slice of code I'm using to unzip these files.

```
import os
import bs4 as bs
import urllib2
import re
from StringIO import StringIO
import zipfile
import tarfile
import requests


def install_packages_locally(compressed_link, directory):
    file_name = '_'.join(compressed_link.split('/')[-1].split('-')[:-1])
    file_ext = compressed_link.split('-')[-1]
    response = requests.get(compressed_link, stream=True)

    if file_name in os.listdir(directory):
        print('Skipping %s' % file_name)
        return True

    zipData = StringIO()

    if file_ext.endswith('.tar.gz'):
        zipData.write(response.raw.read())
        print('writing %s to %s' % (file_name, directory))
        tarData = tarfile.open(fileobj=zipData, mode='r:*')
        tarData.extractall(path=directory)
        tarData.close()
        zipData.close()
        return True

    elif file_ext.endswith('.zip'):
        zipData.write(response.content)
        print('writing %s to %s' % (file_name, directory))
        unzipData = zipfile.ZipFile(zipData)
        unzipData.extractall(path=directory)
        unzipData.close()
        zipData.close()
        return True
```

Answer (score 0):

Answered here : https://www.reddit.com/r/learnpython/comments/dix37i/tarfileextractall_processes_fine_but_doesnt/f3zq1j4?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x

> I found another example that included a call to BytesIO.seek(0) to
>   reset the file pointer to the start:
>
> If fileobj is specified, it is used as an alternative to a file object
>   opened in binary mode for name. It is supposed to be at position 0.
>
> https://docs.python.org/3/library/tarfile.html
>
> So you should add a call to zipData.seek(0) before calling
>   tarfile.open.